# Azure function get path of http trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a http trigger function app which redirects myAPI.com to a version based on the header:

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    var version = req.Headers["x-version"];
    if(version.ToString() == "2"){
        return new RedirectResult("https://v2.myAPI.com", false);
    }
    else{
        return new RedirectResult("https://v1.myAPI.com", false);
    }
}
```

This works. However if I have a path e.g myAPI.com/customPath it returns 404 for myAPI.com/customPath. I want to redirect to https://v1.myAPI.com/customPath. Thought this would be simple; however I am unable to get the original url from within the function app.

When I try `req.Path.Value` it gives me `/api/HttpTrigger1`. How can I get the path or full url of my original post address (myAPI.com/customPath)?

Comment: Where is your azure function? on local?

Comment: Any update on this issue? Could you get the path with my way or did you still have other problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.UriHelper.GetEncodedUrl(req)` to get the full path. It returns the combined components of the request URL in a fully escaped form suitable for use in HTTP headers and other HTTP operations.

[image]